# Open Microsoft Power BI application in kiosk mode sing c#

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, powerbi

I am working on Microsoft Power Bi desktop application. I need to open it in kiosk mode. Is any api or idea to open an desktop app in kiosk mode? (By writing C# code)

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: No nagyben I am looking for the idea.